# How to search across fields for a range of optional values using ActiveRecord in Ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

I'm coding up a search query where the user can search for `Item`s by creator, title, or description, or any combination of the above.

So in my search controller logic I grab the params thusly:

```
creator = params['creator']
title = params['title']
description = params['description']
# todo: do some input validation here
results = nil
cr = User.roughly_named(creator).first
```

What I am doing now is:

```
q = []
q << "creator_id IS #{cr.id}" if cr
q << "title LIKE '%#{title}%'" if title != ''
q << "description LIKE '%#{description}%'" if title != ''
results = Item.where(q.join(' AND ')
```

but surely there is a better way. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: beware to your solution: it is prone to SQL injections. NEVER EVER interpolate strings directly inside queries!!!

Comment: yep agreed - hence my asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes) :

```
res = Item.scoped

res = res.where(["creator_id is ?", cr.id]) if cr
res = res.where(["title like ?", "%#{title}%"]) unless title.empty?
res = res.where(["description like ?", "%#{description}%"]) unless description.empty?
```

When doing `Item.scoped`, you basically do lazy loading. Iterating over `res` will actually execute the query. This is handy when chaining optional where clauses.

PS: prefer the `?` syntax to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: I note now that `Item.scoped` is deprecated and now you just use `Item.all` instead.  Ref http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 1):

You could simply achieve this with regular `where` clause

Or try [dynamic finders](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)? If that does not help either, you could use `method_missing` to create dynamic method call. It's explained [elsewhere](http://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods/)